# Test file permissions on Mono

Tags: c#, mono, file-permissions

I'm working on crossplatform app with Mono. I want to check permissions for RW-access to user that runs application. On NT I can use .GetAccessControl methods (on Mono throws PlatformNotSupported exception), but what to do with *nix and MacOS? Is there any crossplatfrom solutions?

Answer (score 4):

Mono.Unix has UNIX specific implementations:

```
var ufi = new UnixFileInfo("/tmp/test.cpp");
ufi.CanAccess(AccessModes.F_OK); // is a file/directory
ufi.CanAccess(AccessModes.R_OK); // accessible for reading
ufi.CanAccess(AccessModes.W_OK); // accessible for writing
ufi.CanAccess(AccessModes.X_OK); // accessible for executing
FileSpecialAttributes sa = ufi.FileSpecialAttributes; //setuid, setgid and sticky bits
FileAccessPermissions fa = ufi.FileAccessPermissions;
```

FileAccessPermissions is defined as:

```
[Flags ()]
public enum FileAccessPermissions {
    UserReadWriteExecute,
    UserRead,
    UserWrite,
    UserExecute,
    GroupReadWriteExecute,
    GroupRead,
    GroupWrite,
    GroupExecute,
    OtherReadWriteExecute,
    OtherRead,
    OtherWrite,
    OtherExecute,
    DefaultPermissions,
    AllPermissions
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume that it won't work on Windows or it's possible through POSIX subsystem?

Comment: @ViKozh Mmm not sure. You could just try. AFAICT it should still be fair game if it didn't work, as you apparently found that `.GetAccessControl` doesn't work on *NIX... _That_ might have to do with the filesystem driver though (check that (extended) file attributes are enabled?)

Answer (score 1):

How about just trying to open the file for RW and seeing if it succeeds?

Comment: Thanks, actually it's simpler than anything. I'll check if it fits in my case.

Answer (score 0):

`File.GetAttributes(path)`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx

Not as much information as `.GetAccessControl`, but you can determine if the file is `ReadOnly`